# iphone/ipad large canvas vs small canvas + div animation

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, performance, canvas

Since I dont have either of these devices handy to test, which method would be faster on an iphone/ipad?

One large canvas (overlayed over a bg of the same size), that is cleared, and has new pixel data drawn to it each frame, at a certain position

or

A small canvas that updates each frame, contained in a div that is animated across a background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out iphone/ipad aren't even capable of running this small animation either way. I will have to look at alternative solutions for mobile/tablet devices.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've found the iPhone too slow in all my canvas experiment.
Even moving a simple div around (CSS3 styled, no canvas) is barely accettable ( my test with the new motion API: http://www.omiod.com/i.htm )